# atlas mongodb serverless and aws lambda connection issue

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have got a serverless db on atlas (https://www.mongodb.com/serverless). I used the connection string recommended by ATLAS:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@xyz.esxbh.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

however as soon as i try to create a record, i get the following error:

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"MongoParseError: Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet`","reason":{"errorType":"MongoParseError","errorMessage":"Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet`","name":"MongoParseError","stack":["MongoParseError: Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet`","
```

I don't think that the connection string is correct, on the other hand the dns entry for the server does reply with 2 servers.

I tried dropping the '+srv' part, however in that case the save function from mongoose just hangs forever timing out the lambda function.

I could not find any similar problem on google.

The TXT entry record from the dns server shows:

```
"TXT    "authSource=admin&loadBalanced=true"
```

How have you configured the serverless database to work?

The code that generates the error  depends on mongoose and is as follows:

```
        try {
          const customer = new Customer(cust);
          console.log('new cusotmer created');
          const returnedCustomer = await customer.save();
          console.log(returnedCustomer);
          return serverResponse(200, returnedCustomer);
        } catch(err){
          console.log(err);
          return errorHandler(500, err)
        }
```

It seems that the connection to the database is fine:

```
try {
    await dbTools.connectMongoose();
    console.log('*** connected ***');

} catch(err){
    console.log('error when connecting');
    return errorHandler(500, err);
}
```

Now, looking at the source code, nothing really too complicated:

```
if (Object.keys(record).some(key => key !== 'authSource' && key !== 'replicaSet')) {
  return callback(
    new MongoParseError('Text record must only set `authSource` or `replicaSet`')
  );
}
```

I am now really struggling to understand what's wrong as authSource seems to be present in the TXT record.

Comment: The actual connection string looks fine, what line of the code generates this error?

Comment: remove `loadBalanced=true` from TXT record.

Comment: Hey thanks for both answers. I cannot remove loadBalanced=true as this is a service provided by atlas. re- the code that generates the error, it's a simple mongoose save() function:

            try {
              const customer = new Customer(cust);
              console.log('new cusotmer created');
              const returnedCustomer = await customer.save();
              console.log(returnedCustomer);
              return serverResponse(200, returnedCustomer);
            } catch(err){
              console.log(err);
              return errorHandler(500, err)
            }

Comment: @ArbazSiddiqui I think your solution is right, problem is I don't control the server's dns

Comment: I am having the same issue now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Upgrading **mongoose** to the latest version worked for me in **Nodejs**.

1. Remove "**mongoose**" from package.json.
2. **Reinstall** "npm i mongoose"
3. "mongoose version **6.0.5**" should work.

**Worked on 10-Sep-2021**

Comment: Yeah, It is working well. Thanks for your answer, I was also having same issue and you saved me in that.

Comment: Glad to learn that I helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still experiencing this in 2022, here is an answer from a MongoDB employee (at the bottom).  It's a native Node.js driver issue (nothing to do with AWS lambda specifically), which will waterfall to all ODM implementations that implement the native driver.

https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/atlas-serverless-and-dns-txt-record/117967/9

According to Zia Ullah's answer to this same question, this is fixed by Mongoose 6.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error while using mongoimport or another item of mongodb-database-tools, then upgrade your tools to version 100.5.x or later

for mac:
brew upgrade mongodb-database-tools

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/installation/installation-macos/